# Assist me on building my own regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm completely new in this area, I need a regex that follows these rules:

1. Only numbers and symbols are allowed.
2. Must start with a number and ends with a number.
3. Must not contain more than 1 symbol in a row. (for example `123+-4567` is not accepted but `12+345-67` is accepted.

I tried `^[0-9]*[+-*/][0-9]*$` but I think it's a stupid try.

Comment: Are you trying to write a calculator?

Comment: This tool - http://www.regexplained.co.uk/ - can be very handy when trying to work out a regular expression.

Comment: What does the string look like? Does it look like  '`this is a string. I need to match 12+345-67 somewhere in it'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close with your attempt. This one should work.

```
^[0-9]+([+*/-][0-9]+)*$
```

explanation:

- `^` matches beginning of the string
- `[0-9]+` matches 1 or more digits.
- `[+*/-]` matches one from specified symbols
- `([+*/-][0-9]+)*` matches group of symbol followed by at least one digit, repeated 0 or more times
- `$` matches end of string

Comment: Seeing that OP is new to regex, don't you think that some explanation would be required?

Comment: @Jerry Added some explanation.

Comment: I was actually expecting an explanation about the `-` in there, because that's one of the small things that can cause a lot of frustration especially with people new to regex.

Answer (score 1):

We'll build that one from individual parts and then we'll see how we can be smarter about that:

1. Numbers

   ```
   \d+
   ```

   will match an integer. Not terribly fancy, but we need to start somewhere.
2. Must start with a number and end with a number:

   ```
   ^\d+.*\d+$
   ```

   Pretty straightforward. We don't know anything about the part in between, though (also the last `\d+` will only match a single digit; we might want to fix that eventually).
3. Only numbers and symbols are allowed. Depending on the complexity of the rest of the regex this might be easier by explicitly spelling it out or using a negative lookahead to make sure there is no non-(number|symbol) somewhere in the string. I'll go for the latter here because we need that again:

   ```
   (?!.*[^\d+*/-])
   ```

   Sticking this to the start of the regex makes sure that the regex won't match if there is any non-(number|symbol) character anywhere in the string. Also note that I put the `-` at the end of the character class. This is because it has a certain special meaning when used between two other characters in a character class.
4. Must not contain more than one symbol in a row. This is a variation on the one before. We just make sure that there never is more than one symbol by using a negative lookahead to disallow two in sequence:

   ```
   (?!.*[+/*-]{2})
   ```

Putting it all together:

```
(?!.*[^\d+*/-])(?!.*[+/*-]{2})^\d+.*\d+$
```

Testing it:

```
PS Home:\> '123+-4567' -match '(?!.*[^\d+*/-])(?!.*[+/*-]{2})^\d+.*\d+$'
False
PS Home:\> '123-4567' -match '(?!.*[^\d+*/-])(?!.*[+/*-]{2})^\d+.*\d+$'
True
```

---

However, I only literally interpreted your rules. If you're trying to match arithmetic expressions that can have several operands and operators in sequence (but without parentheses), then you can approach that problem differently:

1. Numbers again

   ```
   \d+
   ```
2. Operators

   ```
   [+/*-]
   ```
3. A number followed by an operator

   ```
   \d+[+/*-]
   ```
4. Using grouping and repetition to match a number followed by any number of repetitions of an operator and another number:

   ```
   \d+([+/*-]\d+)*
   ```
5. Anchoring it so we match the whole string:

   ```
   ^\d+([+/*-]\d+)*$
   ```

Generally, for problems where it works, this latter approach works better and leads to more understandable expressions. The former approach has its merits, but most often only in implementing password policies (apart from »cannot repeat any of your previous 30689 passwords«).

Comment: @Jerry, that was more a point in teaching how to approach regex building. You can work off a checklist of requirements, or you can try building a grammar. I just wasn't quite done with the second part ;)

Comment: Lol, okay, +1 for effort :)